# EF5 Entity Sql dbset

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I am using Following method

```
public static ObjectQuery<T> ObjectQueryListQuery<T>(ObjectContext context, string sql)
    {
        var context1 = new NorthwindEntities1();
       // sql =;
        var x = (IObjectContextAdapter) context1;
       // x.ObjectContext.CreateQuery<>()
        ObjectQuery<T> t1;
        t1 = new ObjectQuery<T>(sql, x.ObjectContext);
     //   var customersQuery = t1.ToList();
        var vvv = t1.ToList();
         string[] columns = new string[2];
         columns[0] = "ProductName";
         columns[1] = "ProductID";


         foreach (var t1itm in t1)
        {

            foreach (var column in columns)
            {
                var tp = t1itm.GetType();

                var px = tp.GetProperty(column);
                  var val =  px.GetValue(t1itm, null);
                Console.WriteLine(val);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }

        return t1;
```

I am calling this function

```
var tq=   ObjectQueryListQuery<Product>(p.ObjectContext,  "SELECT VALUE p FROM NorthwindEntities1.Products AS p ");
```

Is there way to remove the  put some thing  generic like `<Dbset>`.  We used to do this EF4 in EF5 i am unable to achive this

Comment: How did you do it in EF4? And why is EF5 different?

Comment: Can you explain your question? It is not clear what are you asking for.

Comment: in EF4 We had String query = "SELECT c.FirstName,c.LastName, c.Title " +
"FROM PEF.Contacts AS c " +
"WHERE c.FirstName='Robert'";
ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord> contacts = context.CreateQuery<DbDataRecord>(query);
foreach (DbDataRecord record in contacts)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
record["Title"].ToString().Trim(),
record["FirstName"].ToString().Trim(),
record["LastName"].ToString().Trim());
}